# PHP Carbon DateTime adds two months and skips november entirely

Tags: php, datetime, time, php-carbon

I need to display three calendars one for the current month and the other two for the next two months.

I am using Carbon to do these calculations.

Today is the 31st of October.

If I write the following

```
$carbon = Carbon::now('UTC'); // current datetime in UTC is 8:54 AM October 31, 2016
echo $carbon->format('F') . '<br>';
echo $carbon->addMonths(1)->format('F');
```

I get this output

> October
>
> December

I am completely missing November... so how do I add a month on to October so that I get November.

Comment: try `addMonths(2)` what is return?

Comment: Not entirely sure, but if you take away 1 day, and then add the one month, what do you get then?

Comment: @Epodax, nicely caught... it shows November, so does that mean something is going wrong with Carbons calculations?

Comment: @Chonchol Mahmud huh, interesting I still get December whether I write $carbon->addMonths(1)->format('F'); or $carbon->addMonths(2)->format('F');

Comment: I haven't used carbon before, but I assume it's because that we have the 31 of October today, and November only has 30 days, so by adding another month it skipped directly to December 1st.

Comment: @JethroHazelhurst this is leap year problem in carbon, i think :/

Comment: @JethroHazelhurst see http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/ this documentation.

Comment: Okay, thanks Chonchol!

Comment: Interesting solution Ryan, I think that would work, I saw a similar answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40339468/php-carbon-month-method-generates-wrong-datetime?noredirect=1#comment67933596_40339468 and it looks like a viable solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default `addMonths(1)` adds exactly 30 days to a month.

To add exactly one month (e.g. to go from October to November regardless of whether it is 29/30/31 days) you need to do away with `addMonth()` and instead use `addMonthsNoOverflow(n)`.

So for example:

```
$carbon = Carbon::now('UTC'); // current datetime in UTC is 8:54 AM October 31, 2016
echo $carbon->format('F') . '<br>';
echo $carbon->addMonths(1)->format('F');
```

unexpectedly Outputs:

**October
December**

Whereas

```
$carbon = Carbon::now('UTC'); // current datetime in UTC is 8:54 AM October 31, 2016
echo $carbon->format('F') . '<br>';
echo $carbon->addMonthsNoOverflow(1)->format('F');
```

Correctly outputs:

**October November**

This behaviour is not due to Carbon but due to the PHP datetime class that it is built on.

The reason `addMonthsNoOverflow()` is NOT the default behaviour is because this would be a 'breaking change'.

You can read more about it in this Github conversation: https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon/issues/627

Answer (score 0):

It's an error in php base lib: `\DateTime`

in your php startup code set:

```
Carbon:: useMonthsOverflow(false);
```

To fix this issue and just be able to use `addMonths()` instead.

Warning though this might break existing code that depends on Carbon, if you had any.