# PHP Carbon "month()" method generates wrong DateTime

Tags: php, datetime, php-carbon

I just stumbled upon something really weird. I use the "Carbon" package to generate DateTime objects.

I use the following code to create a DateTime string for the beginning of September 2016:

```
Carbon::create()->month(9)
```

If I output this using Laravel's "dd()" function, I receive the following output:

```
Carbon\Carbon {
  +"date": "2016-10-01 10:22:36.000000"
  +"timezone_type": 3
  +"timezone": "Europe/Vienna"
}
```

It returns the 1st of October, rather than the 1st of September! It works fine with every other month.

Ive also tried these:

```
Carbon::now()->month(9)
(new Carbon)->month(9)
```

But I get the same wrong result.

Does anyone else experience this bug or can someone please try this out and tell me if you receive the same output? Or am I just doing something wrong, even though I can't think of anything?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am in exactly the same boat as you... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40339101/php-carbon-datetime-adds-two-months-and-skips-november-entirely?noredirect=1#comment67932907_40339101

Comment: It appears to have something to do with today being the 31st and the leap year skipping an entire month. I am really keen to see the solution to this annoying bug as it has messed up my entire scheduling application.

Comment: I don't really know what to do about this, to be honest.

Comment: I think I found a solution deep in the Github issue tracker discussion, let me know if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that the problem is todays date which is the 31st.

`Carbon::create()->month(9)` tries to take the same day for September. Since there is no 31st in September, it returns October 1st. Try:

```
Carbon::create()->day(1)->month(9);
```

Or

```
Carbon::create()->startOfMonth()->month(9);
```

Or

```
Carbon::create(null, 9);
```